# Login function doesn't seem to be functioning correctly

Tags: php, mysql, session

I've been sitting here pondering this for a good 30 minutes now and I just can't see what's wrong.

I've added prints but it just doesn't seem to be contacting the database correctly or not pulling the data from it correctly.

```
$conf['sql_host'] = 'localhost';
$conf['sql_user'] = 'root';
$conf['sql_pass'] = '';
$conf['sql_data'] = 'c_webauth';

    mysql_connect( $conf['sql_host'], $conf['sql_user'], $conf['sql_pass'] ) or die( 'Connection failed: '.mysql_error() );
    mysql_select_db( $conf['sql_data'] );



function login( $user, $pass ){

    session_regenerate_id();
        if ( isset( $_SESSION['user_id'] ) ) {
            unset( $_SESSION['user_id'] );
        }

        $qry = mysql_query( "SELECT user_id, user, user_group, user_name FROM c_users where user='$user' AND pass='".md5($pass)."'" );

        if ( mysql_num_rows( $qry ) > 0 ) {
            session_regenerate_id();

            while ( $data = mysql_fetch_array( $qry ) ) {
                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $data['user_id'];
                $_SESSION['user_group'] = $data['user_group'];
                $_SESSION['user'] = $data['user'];
                $_SESSION['user_name'] = $data['user_name'];

                // Debug
                echo $_SESSION['user_id'];
                echo $_SESSION['user_group'];
                echo $_SESSION['user'];
                echo $_SESSION['user_name'];

                session_start( ); 
            }
        }
}

login( "username", "password" );
```

Anychance you can see whats wrong?

Everyone has mentioned that I had my session_start(); in the wrong place, but the echo's print nothing, absolutely no errors anywhere.

Comment: `session_start()` before echoing and setting session variables?

Comment: Always call `session_start()` at the very top of the page

Comment: why you are putting session_start( );  at bottom , after you have assigned SESSION variables ?

Comment: if it's a new application and you will be updating your PHP version you should stop using mysql_ functions and start using mysqli_ or PDO.

Comment: if you check your web server log I'm sure you will have an error there regarding the SESSIONS variable, and said error is stoping your script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling session_start() at the end instead before doing session checks

Answer (score 2):

`session_start( );`  it should used before session use

Answer (score 2):

You have put `session_start( )` at bottom , after you have assigned SESSION variables

Put this function on top of the page and  remove from bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `session_start()` at the top of your code, because its at the bottom all `$_SESSION` variables are undeclared so they wont return a value. One `session_start()` is at the top you'll get the global `$_SESSION` variables and you'll also be able to set them. I advise that you create a script called `config.php` that has `session_start()` and you can include it in all your scripts instead of add `session_start()` everytime.
Hope this helps you out :D

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I'll keep that in mine! :)

Comment: Hey if I've fixed your problem don't forget to give me a green tick ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
session_start();

$conf['sql_host'] = 'localhost';
$conf['sql_user'] = 'root';
$conf['sql_pass'] = '';
$conf['sql_data'] = 'c_webauth';

    mysql_connect( $conf['sql_host'], $conf['sql_user'], $conf['sql_pass'] ) or die( 'Connection failed: '.mysql_error() );
    mysql_select_db( $conf['sql_data'] );



function login( $user, $pass ){

    session_regenerate_id();
        if ( isset( $_SESSION['user_id'] ) ) {
            unset( $_SESSION['user_id'] );
        }

        $qry = mysql_query( "SELECT user_id, user, user_group, user_name FROM c_users where user='$user' AND pass='".md5($pass)."'" );

        if ( mysql_num_rows( $qry ) > 0 ) {
            session_regenerate_id();

            while ( $data = mysql_fetch_array( $qry ) ) {
                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $data['user_id'];
                $_SESSION['user_group'] = $data['user_group'];
                $_SESSION['user'] = $data['user'];
                $_SESSION['user_name'] = $data['user_name'];

                // Debug
                echo $_SESSION['user_id'];
                echo $_SESSION['user_group'];
                echo $_SESSION['user'];
                echo $_SESSION['user_name'];


            }
        }
}

login( "username", "password" );
?>
```

I've fixed your code for you.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, I'm getting no SQL errors and the data is there to be pulled from the database any ideas?

Comment: Are there any errors on the page, or any errors in error.log in the directory?

Comment: I have 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
set aswell but nothing coming up.

Comment: Have you tried running it on a different host? I had a code that showed absolutely no errors on one hosting, but showed some errors on a different hosting.